# Exit function based on the return parameter of an another function?

Tags: python, loops, return, exit

I'm trying to understand the logic of this code below. Could someone please help me on below questions?

1) Does the `for` loop continues execution because of the return of `check_cheese` is `False`? As far as I know, either the outcome is `True` or `False`, a `return` command stops the execution of a function.

2) Does the `if check_cheese(cheese)` statement returns cheese variable only if the return parameter of `check_cheese()` function is `True`? I'm a bit confused here because there is no check like `==` or `in` or any other statement that indicates to return cheese only if the condition is `True`.

3) What would be the case if Gouda is not existent in the list? Is it going to be like every condition in the `for` loop returns `False` and at the end print statement *you call yourself* will be executed before termination?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

```
def check_cheese(cheese):

    if cheese == "Gouda":
        print("ooh we have that one")
        return True
    print(f"we don't have any {cheese}")
    return False

def find_first_available_cheese():

    for cheese in ['Emmental','Gouda']:
        if check_cheese(cheese):
            return cheese
    print("and you call yourself a cheeseshop!")

find_first_available_cheese()
```

Comment: There is _no_ recursion in your code.

Comment: There's no recursion in your code. You are calling `check_cheese` in `find_first_available_cheese` function. *recursive* function calls itself.

Comment: Thank's for the first question. Please get familiar with formating markups and your questions will look greater.

Answer (score 0):

1. A call to a `return` statement will always break the outer loop / function, even if it is `return False`. In your case, the `if` condition is preventing to call the `return` statement
2. Your `check_cheese` function never returns a `cheese` variable, only booleans
3. Why don't you try? ;)

Comment: OP thinks there's recursion in his code. I think it would be better to mention *there's no recursion in his code*.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes you're right, however there was already two comments stating it before I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does the For loop continues execution because of the return of
>   check_cheese is False? As far as I know, either the outcome is True
>   or False, a return command stops the execution of a function

If you return inside of an if-statement, it will break from the function.

> 2) Does the "if check_cheese(cheese)" statement returns cheese
>   variable only if the return parameter of check_cheese() function is
>   True? I'm a bit confused here because there is no check like "==" or
>   "in" or any other statement that indicates to return cheese only if
>   the condition is True.

The for loop runs until it finds a Gauda cheese, as indicated in the check_cheese function.

> 3) What would be the case if Gouda is not existent in the list? Is it
>   going to be like every condition in the for loop returns False and at
>   the end print statement "you call yourself" will be executed before
>   termination?

You'd get a printout "And you call yourself a cheese shop!". Try. :)